# How can I remove an action link?

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I have a form that I'm creating and I'd like to get rid of the 'Add contract' button that is being put there automatically[image].
Is there something different I can do here:

```
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'my_module', 'includes/admin/my_module.admin.forms');

  return array(
    'my_module_setup_form_contract' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}
```

Or is there some other hook I can use?  I've been looking in the `theme_my_module_setup_form_contract` and `my_module_setup_form_contract`, but it looks like it's too late there.

This is for 7, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove [local actions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/constant/MENU_LOCAL_ACTION/7.x) within [hook_menu_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x).

If this is a generic action it will be removed on all of those forms. E.g. local actions for nodes - changes would be seen on all content types.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I just needed to change my own hook_menu and update the 'type' from MENU_LOCAL_ACTION, to MENU_NORMAL_ITEM.